# OpenGL ES + SDL texture can only be moved with the combination of two keys

Tags: opengl, input, sdl

I making a simple game following JoeyDeVrieses guide on OpenGL, I followed the guide and created an input system, which handles the keyboard inputs and quitting the application, the issue is I cannot control my texture in a proper way, it can only move when I quickly press two keys, also the application doesn't quit when I press the x button

**main.cpp**(Test object is the initialized game class)

```
SDL_Event event;

    while (is_running)
    {
        last_frame = current_frame;
        current_frame = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();

        delta_time = (double)((current_frame - last_frame) * 1000 / (double)SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency());


        if(is_running == false)
            std::cout << "closing application" << std::endl;

       
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            Test.proccess_input(delta_time, event);
            if(event.type == SDL_EVENT_QUIT)
                is_running = false;
        }
        Test.update(delta_time);

        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        Test.render();

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }
```

**game.cpp**

````
void Game::proccess_input(float dt, SDL_Event event)
{
    if (this->State == GAME_ACTIVE)
    {
        float velocity = PLAYER_VELOCITY * dt;

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                case SDL_EVENT_KEY_DOWN:
                    switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                    {
                        case SDLK_a:
                            if (player->position.x >= 0.0f)
                            {
                                player->position.x -= velocity;
                                player->rotation = 270.0f;
                            }
                            break;
                        case SDLK_d:
                            if (player->position.x <= this->width - player->size.x)
                            {
                                player->position.x += velocity;
                                player->rotation = 90.0f;
                            }
                            break;
                        case SDLK_w:
                            if (player->position.y >= 0.0f)
                            {
                                player->position.y -= velocity;
                                player->rotation = 0.0f;
                            }
                            break;
                        case SDLK_s:
                            if (player->position.y <= this->height - player->size.y)
                            {
                                player->position.y += velocity;
                                player->rotation = 180.0f;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple issues with your code.

The first one is that you process events in two locations, which may work correctly in this context, but will eventually explode in your face when you decide to make something a bit more complicated. The core of this issue is that, for instance, a "quit" event may occur the same frame as a "key" event, but since the "key" events are processed in a loop that ignores all other events, the "quit" event is ignored by your code. You should poll for the events in a single loop.

main.cpp

```
...

while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
{
    switch(event.type)
    {
    case SDL_EVENT_QUIT:
    {
        is_running = false;
        break;
    }
    case SDL_EVENT_KEY_DOWN:
    {
        switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_a:
            case SDLK_d:
            case SDLK_w:
            case SDLK_s:
                Test.proccess_input(delta_time, event);
        }
        
        break;
    }
    
    };
}
...
```

game.cpp

```
void Game::proccess_input(float dt, SDL_Event event)
{
    float velocity = PLAYER_VELOCITY * dt;

    switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
    {
        case SDLK_a:
            if (player->position.x >= 0.0f)
            {
                player->position.x -= velocity;
                player->rotation = 270.0f;
            }
            break;
        case SDLK_d:
            if (player->position.x <= this->width - player->size.x)
            {
                player->position.x += velocity;
                player->rotation = 90.0f;
            }
            break;
        case SDLK_w:
            if (player->position.y >= 0.0f)
            {
                player->position.y -= velocity;
                player->rotation = 0.0f;
            }
            break;
        case SDLK_s:
            if (player->position.y <= this->height - player->size.y)
            {
                player->position.y += velocity;
                player->rotation = 180.0f;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The second issue is that SDL may be using the calls from the OS, which will only be active for the frame they occur, and sometimes a "key down" event will "erase" the previous "key down" event, although both keys are down.

The way to solve this is to wrap the events in your own structure which keeps track of which keys are down and which keys are up.

Assuming you have such class variable where you have initialized all your key values to "false": `std::map<int, bool> keyStates;`

main.cpp

```
...

while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
{
    switch(event.type)
    {
    case SDL_EVENT_QUIT:
    {
        is_running = false;
        break;
    }
    case SDL_EVENT_KEY_DOWN:
    {
        switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_a:
            case SDLK_d:
            case SDLK_w:
            case SDLK_s:
                Test.proccess_input(event, true);
        }
        
        break;
    }
    case SDL_EVENT_KEY_UP:
    {
        switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_a:
            case SDLK_d:
            case SDLK_w:
            case SDLK_s:
                Test.proccess_input(event, false);
        }
        
        break;
    }
    
    };
}
Test.update_player_input(dt)
...
```

game.cpp

```
void Game::proccess_input(SDL_Event event, bool isKeyDown)
{
    keyStates[event.key.keysym.sym] = isKeyDown;
}

void Game::update_player_input(float dt)
{
    float velocity = PLAYER_VELOCITY * dt;

    if (keyStates[SDLK_a])
    {
        if (player->position.x >= 0.0f)
        {
            player->position.x -= velocity;
            player->rotation = 270.0f;
        }
    }

    if (keyStates[SDLK_d])
    {
        if (player->position.x <= this->width - player->size.x)
        {
            player->position.x += velocity;
            player->rotation = 90.0f;
        }
    }

    if (keyStates[SDLK_w])
    {
        if (player->position.y >= 0.0f)
        {
            player->position.y -= velocity;
            player->rotation = 0.0f;
        }
    }

    if (keyStates[SDLK_s])
    {
        if (player->position.y <= this->height - player->size.y)
        {
            player->position.y += velocity;
            player->rotation = 180.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach, though, and assuming that your texture only has 4 directions, there will be a bias toward the keys handled last when hitting more than one key, and so the texture will always face the same direction when two keys are pressed.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer, I was on a crunch so I just reverted back to my previous version, which had only one input system and worked 80%(not ideal) of the time. I will test out your solution tomorrow and accept your answer.

Comment: @koogel no worries, good luck!

Comment: This is epic, thank you very much, the application now clothes without issues, there is no delay in between player input and I don't need to press two keys to move the character